# Login form on top nav with zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I've already learned bootstrap but I'm trying to learn foundation for a different project just to get some exposure to it. I'm wondering if there's any simple way to add a username/password form to the top nav bar similar to how bootstrap does? I've checked out the template called workspace here: http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates/workspace.html and it has a search box in the top that looks very similar to what I want, but when I wrap a form around it, it goes haywire. Anybody have an idea how to do this in foundation?

What I'm trying to work with:

```
<nav class="top-bar contain-to-grid">
    <ul>
      <li class="name"><img src="/images/betalogo.jpg"></li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>

    <section>
      <ul class="left">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="right">
        <li>
              <input type="text">
        </li>
        <li>
              <input type="password">
        </li>

        <li class="has-button">
          <input type="submit" class="small button" value="Log In">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the source…

```
<ul class="right">
  <li class="search">
    <form>
      <input type="search">
    </form>
  </li>

  <li class="has-button">
    <a class="small button" href="#">Search</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This will get you the UI you want but not necessarily the functionality. I find the issue with this is that the submit button is outside the form—thereby useless; unless you use some JS to glue the button to the form which, frankly, breaks [K.I.S.S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Alternatively, you could use new rows inside your form. Thanks to Foundation's row nesting. Be sure to `.collapse` the row is you want the button to be right beside the search bar; omit this to keep the gutter between columns.

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old thread and i am sure you figured this out by now, but maybe someone else can use the answer.

```
<!-- Right Nav Section -->
```

<

```
ul class="right">
  <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Radio</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/responsive/blog/">Blog</a></li>
  </li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <?php if(empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){ ?>
  <li class="has-form signinform">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="columns username">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="columns password">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        </div>

      </div>

    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" class="button">
</form>
<?php } 
######end show login######
?>
</ul>
```

This is just a past from my page, but you can see if you need to put a form in it you have to use the class "has-form" in the li tag

Comment: I actually submitted a pull request and they merged it: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/1239 - unfortunately it was removed in 4.0